# Sending bulk SMS via Twilio

Tags: twilio

Is it possible, and if yes, how, to send bulk SMS from csv upload to my customers with an existing Twilio phone number? I looked for such a service, but I cannot find any service for that.
Do anyone know a Joomla plugin for sending SMSs to a Twilio phone number? (without JoomSMS, I use is already but it is absolutely not working).

Could you please help me with that both question?

Comment: You may want to break this out into 2 different posts/questions.  The first asking about bulk SMS with Twilio and the second about using Joomla to send SMS.  This will help the community better answer both for you.

Comment: Twilio SMS does support bulk SMS by using a [Messaging Service](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/services) with multiple phone numbers in the service's Sender Pool. The more phone numbers added, the more throughput you get.
However, Twilio provides the APIs for this, but does not provide pre-made integrations for CMS's. So, you have to develop the solution yourself, or find a vendor that supports this capability.